# Tranform JSON structure to flat array with DataWeave

Tags: dataweave

```
{
  "currentPage": "0",
  "numberElements": "1",
  "continuable": null,
  "hasNextPage": "false",
  "totalOfRecords": "1",
  "totalOfPages": "1",
  "result": [
    {
      "idRelatorio": "000000010",
      "saldos": [
        {
          "testId": "0000002",
          "relatorios": [
            
          ]
        },
        {
          "testId": "02045120",
          "relatorios": [
            {
              "relatorioId": "001001",
              "dataHora": "2022-01-01T00:00:00",
              "relatorio": "test 1",
              "custoRelatorio": "170.00",
              "controleRelatorio": "001_2022"
            },
            {
              "relatorioId": "001002",
              "dataHora": "2022-02-02T00:00:00",
              "relatorio": "test 2",
              "custoRelatorio": "110.00",
              "controleRelatorio": "001_2022"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "testId": "03132311",
          "relatorios": [
            {
              "relatorioId": "001003",
              "dataHora": "2022-03-03T00:00:00",
              "relatorio": "test 3",
              "custoRelatorio": "140.00",
              "controleRelatorio": "003_2022"
            },
            {
              "relatorioId": "001004",
              "dataHora": "2022-02-02T00:00:00",
              "relatorio": "test 4",
              "custoRelatorio": "90.00",
              "controleRelatorio": "004_2022"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "testId": "103125468",
          "relatorios": [
            {
              "relatorioId": "001004",
              "dataHora": "2022-01-01T00:00:00",
              "relatorio": "test 5",
              "custoRelatorio": "130.00",
              "controleRelatorio": "004_2022"
            },
            {
              "relatorioId": "001005",
              "dataHora": "2022-02-02T00:00:00",
              "relatorio": "test 6",
              "custoRelatorio": "100.00",
              "controleRelatorio": "005_2022"
            },
            {
              "relatorioId": "001006",
              "dataHora": "2022-02-02T00:00:00",
              "relatorio": "test 7",
              "custoRelatorio": "80.00",
              "controleRelatorio": "006_2022"
            },
            {
              "relatorioId": "001007",
              "dataHora": "2022-02-02T00:00:00",
              "relatorio": "test 8",
              "custoRelatorio": "200.00",
              "controleRelatorio": "007_2022"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to turn this JSON into a body model as example below in dataweave (mulesoft), if anyone can assist me in this demand.

```
            {
              "relatorioId": "001001",
              "dataHora": "2022-01-01T00:00:00",
              "relatorio": "test 1",
              "custoRelatorio": "170.00",
              "controleRelatorio": "001_2022"
            },
            {
              "relatorioId": "001002",
              "dataHora": "2022-02-02T00:00:00",
              "relatorio": "test 2",
              "custoRelatorio": "110.00",
              "controleRelatorio": "001_2022"
            },
          

            {
              "relatorioId": "001003",
              "dataHora": "2022-03-03T00:00:00",
              "relatorio": "test 3",
              "custoRelatorio": "140.00",
              "controleRelatorio": "003_2022"
            },
            {
              "relatorioId": "001004",
              "dataHora": "2022-02-02T00:00:00",
              "relatorio": "test 4",
              "custoRelatorio": "90.00",
              "controleRelatorio": "004_2022"
            },
            {
              "relatorioId": "001004",
              "dataHora": "2022-01-01T00:00:00",
              "relatorio": "test 5",
              "custoRelatorio": "130.00",
              "controleRelatorio": "004_2022"
            },
            {
              "relatorioId": "001005",
              "dataHora": "2022-02-02T00:00:00",
              "relatorio": "test 6",
              "custoRelatorio": "100.00",
              "controleRelatorio": "005_2022"
            },
            {
              "relatorioId": "001006",
              "dataHora": "2022-02-02T00:00:00",
              "relatorio": "test 7",
              "custoRelatorio": "80.00",
              "controleRelatorio": "006_2022"
            },
            {
              "relatorioId": "001007",
              "dataHora": "2022-02-02T00:00:00",
              "relatorio": "test 8",
              "custoRelatorio": "200.00",
              "controleRelatorio": "007_2022"
            }
```

Comment: Hi @Robson. Please translate your question to English first. Please read Stackoverflow policy for questions in other languages: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/, Also note that the expected answer is not valid JSON. Maybe you intended it to be an array?

Comment: For the future use correctly formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear because of formatting but it looks like you need something like this.
`flatten(payload..relatorios)`

It will collect all relatorios array to first give you an array of arrays, and then flatten it.

Comment: thanks but met very well in my array